# Easy static link for a Flattr thing

Tags: flattr

I would like to easily add a Flattr button to my RSS feed, without any JS

As I understand that each thing on flattr is identified by its URL, I would like to simply add a link like this:

http://flattr.com/thing-by-url/my-url.com/my-new-post

If the thing does not exist, it should be created the first time someone Flattr it (just like my blog does with JS)

From what I can read from the API, it is not currently possible and there's no way to add a static JS-less button in a RSS feed.

What can I do ? Why isn't it possible to have a direct static link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the http://developers.flattr.net/feed/?

You can also add a static button with [auto submit URL](http://developers.flattr.net/auto-submit/) in feed body.

Comment: I didn't know the flattr feed thing. Of course it is not useful yet (chicken and egg) but a good idea. Thanks for the auto-submit URL, that's what I was looking for but I overlooked it.